# How can I determine if a pump bottle's nozzle can be locked?

Tags: travel

A friend in Japan handed me [the Pharma-Act Japanese hair conditioner bottle beneath by Kumano Comestics](https://www.nattacosme.com/Kumano-Yushi-Additive-Free-Conditioner-600ml). I don't know a word of Japanese. Thus please see the question in the title.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An interesting variant is when you have a bottle that is already in use and want to find out if its nozzle can be locked (because, say, you forgot, or somebody else put the bottle to first use).

In this case, unscrew the whole cap, point the nozzle back into the bottle, press down on the pump mechanism and try to lock the nozzle by turning it right. If it stays down, it is obviously lockable.

The advantage of this hack is, you did not spill and waste any content of the bottle, as you poured it back into its own bottle. The same technique is useful when packing a pump bottle for traveling.

Answer (score 1):

If the pump is completely down when you buy it, and you need to ‘unscrew’ the nozzle prior to first use, it has a screw thread and should be lockable (by doing the reverse).